# search a string having special character

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I need to search a string which contains special characters

eg
**keyword = alpha#bet+a**

**db.collection.find('course.title': { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } )**

but i am getting errors like keyword cannot be empty, also invalid regex expression

i even tried by putting backslash before special characters
**keyword.trim().replace(/[^a-z\d#&]/g, '\$&')**

this works for few but not for all.

I am using reactjs as frontend and nodejs ,mongodb for backend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Regex with multiple string having special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102921/mongodb-regex-with-multiple-string-having-special-character)

Comment: This is not working when i use # and & as special characters.But for rest all special characters it works

Answer (score 0):

Following is the query to search string with special characters in a MongoDB document. Here, we are searching for a string keyword with special character $

db.searchDocumentWithSpecialCharactersDemo.find({ field_name: /.*\alpha#bet+a.*/i }).pretty();